# How to delete files like 'Incoming11781rKD'

Tags: bash

I have a programme that is generating files like this "Incoming11781Arp", and there is always `Incoming`, and there is always 5 numbers, but there are 3 letters/upper-case/lower-case/numbers/special case `_` in any way. Like `Incoming11781_pi`, or `Incoming11781rKD`.

How can I delete them using a script run from a cron job please? I've tried -

```
#!/bin/bash
file=~/Mail/Incoming******
rm "$file";
```

but it failed saying that there was no matching file or directory.

Comment: `rm ~/Mail/Incoming*` wouldn't work?

Comment: `rm ~/Mail/Incoming????????`

Comment: Also do you have control over where the program puts the files? you could just put them in their own folder then have a cron job delete it every night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **mustn't double-quote the variable reference for pathname expansion to occur** - if you do, the wildcard characters are treated as literals.
Thus:

```
rm $file
```

**Caveat**: `~/Mail/Incoming******` doesn't work the way you think it does and will potentially match *more* files than intended, as it is equivalent to `~/Mail/Incoming*`, meaning that *any* file that *starts* with `Incoming` will match.

To only match files starting with `Incoming` that are followed by *exactly 6* characters, use `~/Mail/Incoming??????`, as @Jidder suggests in a comment.

---

Note that you could make your glob (pattern) even more specific:

```
file=~/Mail/Incoming[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][[:alpha:]_][[:alpha:]_][[:alpha:]_]
```

See the `bash` manual for a description of pathname expansion and pattern syntax: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion.

Comment: You probably meant `~/Mail/Incoming*` when you said `as it is equivalent to ~/Mail/Incoming******`

Comment: @Ploutox: Whoopsie! Yes, of course - thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect with the `find` command...

```
$ directory='~/Mail/'
$ file_pattern='Incoming*'
$ find "${directory}" -name "${file_pattern}" -delete
```

The first two lines define the directory and the file pattern separately, the `find` command will then proceed to delete any matching files inside that directory.

Comment: Your answer is useful for deleting matching files in an entire _subtree_, which, however, differs from what the OP's code is attempting to do.